# HashMap Duplicate Key Replacement java

Tags: java, hashmap

i have this thing to , lets say  HashMap> has <> "11,name2,name1" and "14,name4,name5"...so I'm trying to remove 11 first and all its data name2 and name1 will be transferred to 14. But the problem is 14's own original data name4 and name 5 are overwritten. I want to keep them all in 14. How should i do that? Hope you can help me with it. Thank you.

```
List<String> oldValue = map.remove(oldKey);
map.put(newKey, oldValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following way. Extract old list from the old key. And add list items to the list of the new key.

```
// remove old key
    List<String> oldValue = map.remove(oldKey);
    // add new key with empty list if not exists
    if(!map.containsKey(newKey))
    {
        map.put(newKey, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
    // new list for new value
    List<String> newValue = map.get(newKey);
    // add items from old value to new list
    for(String s : oldValue){
        // eliminate possible duplicates
        if(!newValue.contains(s)){
            newValue.add(s);
        }
    }
```